# jQuery - Add ID instead of Class

Tags: jquery

I'm using the current [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('span .breadcrumb').each(function(){
        $('#nav').addClass($(this).text());
        $('#container').addClass($(this).text());
        $('.stretch_footer').addClass($(this).text())
        $('#footer').addClass($(this).text());
    });
});
```

It applies the text held in the breadcrumb to 4 elements on the page, allowing me to style specifically to the page there on.

I'd like to try adding an ID instead of a class, how can I achieve this?

Comment: An ID must be unique to be valid XHTML. An ID must match tighter rules, e.g., no spaces, start with letter or _, only contain letters, numbers or a limited number of other characters.

Comment: @Peter: adding a link to wikipedia seems a little redundant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding attribute in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery)

Comment: See also [addID in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657702/6353323)

Comment: In doing this you must also use a unique id for each element in the DOM or it will produce invalid HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('element').attr('id', 'value');
```

So it becomes;

```
$(function() {
    $('span .breadcrumb').each(function(){
        $('#nav').attr('id', $(this).text());
        $('#container').attr('id', $(this).text());
        $('.stretch_footer').attr('id', $(this).text())
        $('#footer').attr('id', $(this).text());
    });
});
```

So you are changing/overwriting the id of three elements and adding an id to one element.
You can modify as per you needs...

Comment: How about caching? Rather than making 4 different jQuery objects of "this".  var text = $(this).text();

Comment: @petersendidt: agreed, i said in my answer, that he needs to modify as per needs.

Comment: even better: `$('#nav, #container, .stretch_footer, #footer').attr('id', $(this).text());` .. not that using an ID here is a good idea.

Comment: This will only work once, after which the ID changes... also, you keep overriding the same IDs, so you might as well do it for `$('#nav, #container, .stretch_footer, #footer').attr('id', $('span .breadcrumb:first').text())` (or `last`, for `.stretch_footer`). Anyway, this is weird.

Comment: This creates multiple elements with the same ID which is invalid HTML

Answer (score 28):

Keep in mind this overwrites any ID that the element already has:

```
 $(".element").attr("id","SomeID");
```

The reason why `addClass` exists is because an element can have multiple classes, so you wouldn't want to necessarily overwrite the classes already set. But with most attributes, there is only one value allowed at any given time.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('selector').attr( 'id', 'yourId' );
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to 'add to the id' rather than replace it

capture the current id first, then append your new id. especially useful for twitter bootstrap which uses input states on their forms.

```
    new_id = '{{old_id}} inputSuccess';
    old_id = that.attr('id');
    that.attr('id', new_id.replace( /{{old_id}}/ig,old_id));
```

if you do not - you will lose any properties you previous set.

hth,

Comment: A valid element can only have a single id. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids

Answer (score 3):

Im doing this in coffeescript

```
booking_module_time_clock_convert_id = () ->
  if $('.booking_module_time_clock').length
    idnumber = 1
    for a in $('.booking_module_time_clock')
      elementID = $(a).attr("id")
      $(a).attr( 'id', "#{elementID}_#{idnumber}" )
      idnumber++
```