# jquery id vs. class trouble

Tags: jquery, class

Right now I have a bunch of images stored in an array. I want those images to have ids of "left_slot", "middle_slot", and "right_slot". The following code works to give them those class names but not ids:

```
 function popArr() {
        $("#thumb_slider").children().each(function (index, element) {
            var newImg = $("<img />").attr({
                src: this.src,
                alt: 'space'
            }).addClass(index == 0 ? "left_slot" : (index == 1 ? "middle_slot" : "right_slot"));
            imgArr.push(newImg);
        });
        return imgArr;
    }
```

My question is, how would I change this function to give them ids depending on their index, instead of classes? I think the classes are getting mixed up with some other sections of code that I have elsewhere on the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attr instead of addClass:

```
function popArr() {
    $("#thumb_slider").children().each(function (index, element) {
        var newImg = $("<img />").attr({
            src: this.src,
            alt: 'space',
            id: index == 0 ? "left_slot" : (index == 1 ? "middle_slot" : "right_slot")
        })
        imgArr.push(newImg);
    });
    return imgArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176986/jquery-add-id-instead-of-class) out.  So use the "id" attribute instead of the addClass function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.addClass()`, use `.prop( "id", ..... )`