# Is it possible to assign and Input ID to a class?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the gravity forms plugin for Wordpress and I can assign a class to individual inputs. I have a form field called "Email" and I want to assign it to a class called "Email" that automatically gives this input an id of "Email". So even if I wanted an input asking for your first name to have an input id of "Email", all i would have to do is assign it to to the email class. Is it possible to use CSS to automatically assign an input id via and input class? What would this CSS class look like?

Comment: You want to automatically assign an `id` to elements based on their `class`? Can you show the HTML you're working with, the 'input', and what you want that HTML to look like after manipulation via jQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

CSS can not set the attributes of an element.

Only JavaScript can edit the attributes (id, name, type, value, etc) of an HTML element.

What is the desired outcome that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, But a CSS class can not do things such as assigning logic. CSS is for styling. If you want an input to have an ID & class of email, you would need to assign them individually (the class can not assign the ID for you).

It would be possible to use jQuery or JavaScript to retrieve the class of the input and then assign it as the ID. But that would only be useful if you expect the class name to change or be generated dynamically.

[SO post about Adding ID with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176986/jquery-add-id-instead-of-class).

Adding a class is also pretty simple: [jQuery Docs - addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$("p").addClass("myClass");
```