# How to add ID to input field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My Javascript code is something like this:

```
if (editMode === true) {
    var divId = element.attr('id');
    console.log(divId);
}

var textBox = $('<input class="my-text-box" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" />');
```

I want to set `divId` variable as the ID in this...

```
var textBox = $('<input class="my-text-box" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" />');
```

This `divId` variable needs to have dynamic values. Please help me to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Add ID instead of Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176986/jquery-add-id-instead-of-class)

Comment: Do you want to put divId in place of this.value ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtBox = $('.my-text-box');
txtBox.prop('id', 'newIdHere');
```

don't try to select an element by the entire element html like you were , ex.

```
var textBox = $('<input class="my-text-box" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divId = null;
if (editMode === true) {
    divId = element.attr('id');
    console.log(divId);
}

$('.my-text-box').attr('id', divId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just concat that id with html

```
if (editMode === true) {
var divId = element.attr('id');
console.log(divId);}

var textBox = $( '<input class="my-text-box" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" id="'+divId+'" />');
```