# Appending ID without replacing original

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append an ID to div elements, but it seems if there is already an ID it replaces the existing. I'm at a loss.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("div").each( function(i){
                    $(this).attr({ id: " num_" + ++i });
                })
            });
```

Comment: you can only add one ID to an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addID in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657702/addid-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div").each( function(i){
           $(this).attr({ id: $(this).attr("id") + " num_" + ++i });
     })
});
```

Comment: Furkan Başaran, that did the trick, thank you! Now the next issue is if there is no existing ID it's appending "unidentified." 

I am also experiencing some some jQuery version conflict. I get no errors, but in this example you can see where the mobile menu is not working http://sandbox.iemajen.com/ where the append ID is running, and in this example where it is not but the mobile menu is working - http://jacobsladderky.com/

Answer (score 0):

A div element can only have one identifier and this identifier must be unique.
So you can't append an id.

Answer (score 0):

An element in html have atmost single id. To solve this problem use customised attributes. Start using 'data-id' and use them as the normal html attributes. If you want to add more ids you just increment number. like...
input id='name' data-id='username'