# assigning DOM attributes with javascript's createElement function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a table with elements from a database. I am using this function to render the elements in the HTML

```
function tableToHTML(tableData) {
var table = document.createElement('table'), 
tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
});

table.appendChild(tableBody);
document.body.appendChild(table);

}
```

Can I somehow assign id or class attributes to the created `tr`s or `td`s within the javascript? I am using the Meteor framework, so jQuery is fair game if it is simpler to do with jQuery.

Comment: `cell.id = whatever;`. `cell.className="tdClass";`

Comment: Yup, just assign the id like you would any other node.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class using `.className = 'class'`, and an ID using `.id = 'ID'`:

```
var elem = document.createElement('td')
elem.className = 'myClass'
elem.id = 'myId'
```

This will result in an element like so:

```
<td id="myId" class="myClass"></td>
```

You can also use jQuery's [`.addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add a class, and `.attr` for the ID (check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657706/5620297))

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can create an object and assign attributes to it all in one call, by supplying the attributes in an object argument.

```
var cell = $("<td>", {
    "class": "myClass",
    "id": "myId"
});
```