# How to add id in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created one dialog box in jquery. and there is one button called 'save'. I need to add one id to this save buttton. How can I achive in this in jquery. This is my code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

         height: 400,
      width: 650,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {

        Save: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: try this `Save: {
 id: 'Save',
 click: function() {
  dialog.dialog( "close" );
 }
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Add ID instead of Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176986/jquery-add-id-instead-of-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657702/addid-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("button").attr("id","testid");`

Answer (score 2):

The Save function has a parameter `event` which has a target that is the DOM element of the button, then you can set the id inside of the function like this:

```
Save: function(event) {
   $(event.target).attr('id', 'your-id');
}
```

The [specification](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) about the `buttons` property says:

> Specifies which buttons should be displayed on the dialog. The context of the callback is the dialog element; if you need access to the button, **it is available as the target of the event object.**

Answer (score 2):

This is the most simplest

```
$(selector).attr('id', 'TheID');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$(element).attr('id', 'YourNewID');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      height: 400,
      width: 650,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        save: {
          text: "Save",
          id: "my-button-id",
          click: function(){
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
          }   
        }
      }
      ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valid reply. I have one more doubt that how can I access this id in my js file.$("#rm-button-id").click(function(){
  alert("here");
 });

Comment: This is what I am using now.